# Conditional formatting of line colour in plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Matplotlib has some excellent styling options but is it possible to conditionally format the line colour in a line plot?

Specifically:

- line solid black when below 0
- line solid red when above 0

Please see the example below that I have photoshopped - the bar chart can be ignored...

[image: Example output]

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't found that and will close my question as it looks to be the same

Comment: Don't close it, it's better to leave it as a duplicate. This way the answer may be easier to find for others.